# How would I have guessed to rearrange and use the fact that any number squared is positive in this induction proof in Abbott's Understanding Analysis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, proof-writing, soft-question

In Abbott's Analysis, there's a question here:

> Exercise 2.4.5 (Calculating Square Roots). Let $x_1=2$, and define $$
> > x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}\right) $$ (a) Show that
> $x_n^2$ is always greater than or equal to 2 , and then use this to
> prove that $x_n-x_{n+1} \geq 0$. Conclude that $\lim x_n=\sqrt{2}$.

And (part) of the answer here:

> Exercise 2.4.5. (a) We first observe that a simple induction argument
> shows that $x_n$ is positive for all $n$. We can also write $$
> > x_{n+1}^2-2=\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}\right)\right)^2-2=\frac{x_n^2}{4}+\frac{1}{x_n^2}-1=\left(\frac{x_n}{2}-\frac{1}{x_n}\right)^2
> > \geq 0 $$ as any number squared is positive. This shows that $x_n^2
> > \geq 2$ for all choices of $n$.
>
> ... more stuff

When I was solving it, I kept trying to prove it by just saying saying okay $x_1^2 >=2$ so if we assume $x_n^2 >=2$ then to prove that implies $x_{n+1}^2 >=2$ we need to first expand out $x_{n+1}^2$ squared like so:

$$
x_{n+1}^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}\right)^2=\frac{x_n^2}{4}+\frac{1}{x_n^2}+1$$

and then start plugging in our $x_{n+1}^2 >=2$

so then
$$x_{n+1}^2= \frac{x_n^2}{4}+\frac{1}{x_n^2}+1>=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{x_n^2}+1 >= \frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{x_n^2}$$

so then I'd look at it and think okay now all we need is to prove that $\frac{1}{x_n^2} >= \frac{1}{2}$ and then we will have $x_{n+1}^2 >= 2$ like we want.

So then I'd search for something in the form $x_n^2 < 2$ But of course this can't be true, since $x_1^2$ is already = 4 which is not < 2

And I know that doesn't disprove anything. That of course $x_{n+1}^2$ could still be more than 2 because I used the >= replacement too haphazardly/early after all, but this is the path my brain goes down and I want to figure out how to think the way I need to instead D:

Comment: Like I do admire Abbott's trick. Try something with $(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n})(x_n-\frac{2}{x_n})\,.$

Comment: Alt. hint: $\,$ $x_n$ is positive, then by AM-GM $\;\displaystyle
\require{cancel}
x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}}{2} \ge \sqrt{x_n \cdot\frac{2}{x_n}} = \sqrt{2} \iff x_{n+1}^2 \ge 2\,$.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, the problem arose when you lower-bounded $\frac{x_n^2}4$ alone, leaving $\frac1{x_n^2}$ orphan, instead of lower-bounding the whole $x_n+\frac2{x_n}$ which appeared earlier in your calculations.

Your induction step had to be
$$x_n^2\ge2\implies x_n+\frac2{x_n}\ge2\sqrt2.$$
You could prove this methodically, without any trick: for any $x>0,$
$$x+\frac2x\ge2\sqrt2\iff x^2+2\ge2\sqrt2x$$
$$\iff x^2-2\sqrt2x+2\ge0$$
and since the discriminant of $x^2-2\sqrt2x+2$ is $0,$ this inequation is always satisfied. And actually, induction was only needed previously, to prove that $x_n>0.$